# API is slow when open website page by using domain and fast when open using IP address

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, webserver, laravel-9

I have developed one website page in ReactJs in which some APIs are calling an API implemented in Lravel. I am using ReactJS 16.2.0 and Laravel 9.32.0.

When I open this page by using a domain like https://example.com/dashboard, it takes lots of time to load the API but when I open the same page through the IP address https://x.x.x.x/dashboard, it loads all API responses faster.

Thanks.